# What is the word for "Unnecessary detailed information"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Can you tell me what the word is for "Unnecessary detailed info on a topic which is given after the prominent parts is given"?

Comment: I found this as I was looking for "unnecessary attribution" - hope that helps someone else.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could say that it is [extraneous](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/extraneous):

> not pertinent; irrelevant: an extraneous remark; extraneous decoration.

Answer (score 8):

If someone doesn't stay on topic, you might say their unrelated information is a [*digression*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/digression)  or that they've gone off on a [*tangent*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tangent#Noun).

If they simply go on at length, they might [*ramble*](http://thesaurus.com/browse/ramble), *drivel*, *blather*, or *babble*, producing some form of [*nonsense*](http://thesaurus.com/browse/nonsense), perhaps *claptrap* or *prattle*.

Answer (score 4):

The word you're looking for is ***superfluous***

From the Oxford Dictionary:

> **[superfluous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/superfluous)** - Unnecessary, especially through being more than enough:

Comment: Generally you would want to include some citation, but good.

Answer (score 2):

Following on aedia λ's answer:

*Digressive* might be another alternative.

Merriam-Webster:

> digressive: characterized by digressions

Edited to include definition based on Sven's suggestion.

Comment: From the way the poster framed the question, I suspect that he's looking for a noun rather than for an adjective. But in any event you can strengthen your answer by adding a dictionary definition of _digressive_, citing the dictionary, and (if possible) including a link to it.

Comment: You're right of course. But the top-rated response also proposes only an adjective.

Comment: So it does, so it does. And the poster accepted it, so he can hardly have been too keen on nouns versus adjectives. Anyway I appreciate your taking time to revise your answer to help it stand on its own a bit better. +1

Comment: Of course! It was a good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

We could call it "information overload":

> The inability to process everything one hears and sees; the availability or supply of too much information, or a state of stress which results.

"information overload" is the result of too much information, and perhaps, can be used to refer to the "too much information" itself

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're referring to printed material of some sort, you might be referring to a 'disclaimer', 'statutory legalese', aka 'the fine print'.

Comment: Actually it doesn't relate to printed material. It could be everything like a speech or something or a story..

Comment: Lets assume "Some one is giving a speech about something but in the middle of his speech he just decided to give such info not relevant to the topic and then quickly got back to the topic" but he did it on purpose and this is something not necessary and also detail info  about the topic.